# How to identify more than 4 gb ram on 32-bit machine

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I know that a 32-bit OS cannot see more than 4 GB of RAM.
So if I were to install, say, 6 GB of RAM on a machine running 32-bit OS, is there any way to identify that?
I know one way to get the installed RAM is through WMI class: win32_physicalmemory.Capacity
But I don't know if it'll show the correct installed ram size rather than supported.
I don't have the setup to test this scenario, but if some one already knows this, please confirm.
Else, please let me know if there's some other way of doing the same. I'm asking this for any  windows 32-bit OS.

Thanks in advance.
Samrat Patil.

Comment: "I know that a 32-bit OS cannot see more than 4 GB of RAM." Not true. With Physical Address Extension (PAE) feature supported by the processor and software techniques like Address Windowing Extensions (AWE), you can access more than 4GB of memory (e.g. WinServer2003 Enterprise can use it).  The thing is, at a single point of time, a single process can access 4GB of address space.

Comment: and it makes a number of drivers fall over and die horribly ;)

Comment: @jalf, which sometimes seems to be the default behavior of drivers anyway. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32bit operating systems CAN see more than 4GB of memory with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)-enabled CPUs. It's just that the 32bit address space is limited to 4GB. But as the application has only access to its own virtual address space, it can't tell if some memory it allocated lays in 1st or 5th gigabyte of memory.

On windows, you can use the [GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300158(VS.85).aspx) function:

> function retrieves the amount of physically installed RAM from the computer's SMBIOS firmware tables. This can differ from the amount reported by the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function, which sets the ullTotalPhys member of the MEMORYSTATUSEX structure to the amount of physical memory that is available for the operating system to use.

Read more:
http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=notes/windows/license/memory.htm

Answer (score 1):

WMI reports all memory sizes as `uint64` as can be seen in the [documentation for Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is quite nice function [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28VS.85%29.aspx) that should solve your problem. It gives back

```
typedef struct _MEMORYSTATUSEX {
  DWORD     dwLength;
  DWORD     dwMemoryLoad;
  DWORDLONG ullTotalPhys;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailPhys;
  DWORDLONG ullTotalPageFile;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailPageFile;
  DWORDLONG ullTotalVirtual;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailVirtual;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
}MEMORYSTATUSEX, *LPMEMORYSTATUSEX;
```

I think you are looking for `ullTotalPhys`. All values are in bytes.